# passport authentication or JWT authentication. Which one is better?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, jwt

What's the tecnical difference between passport authentication and JWT?

I did a shopping cart project on the academic channel from youtube. in that project they used PassportJS, as a result I was wondering what is the difference between them?

Comment: I think I know which course you are talking about, can you send the link? if it is the same course, it is easier to give a opinion!

Comment: Passport is an authentication framework that can use among other things: Facebook, username/password and yes, passport can even use JWT (http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/). JWT on the other hand is an authentication method. You can use JWT if you use passport - no problem. But if you use JWT without passport you cannot use the other things Passport provide such as Facebook/Google login etc.

Comment: On the other hand, if you don't need the features passport provide it is sometimes simpler to just roll your own eg. use JWT directly or manually process cookie sessions (an alternative to JWT)